# Install PHP without web server for Composer..?

Tags: php, composer-php

I need to be able to use Composer on my local machine, however, I don't want to setup a full web server stack on this machine because I'm using my remote server for that.

When I try to install Composer, though, it wants me to point out my PHP install, which I don't have in this case.

Is there a way I can install PHP on its own so that I can also get Composer installed without installing a full stack?

I've always used WAMP in the past, but again, I'd like to avoid installing that whole stack.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not install just PHP? http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: The PHP CLI can be installed without all the webserver stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could install only binary package for PHP. You did not state which operating system are you using.

- [Binary package links (for MacOS)](https://php-osx.liip.ch/)
- [Binary package for Windows](http://windows.php.net/download)

Comment: I'm on Windows.  Can I simply extract the zip file and then point Composer to the php.exe, or is there more of an install process to it than that?

Comment: Just extract and point to php.exe, make sure that php.exe file is put inside a folder that is visible inside PATH folder (like `C:\Windows\system32`)